# Disable orientation for Keyboard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, orientation

I need to support only Portrait mode for Keyboard view.

Because, I have an UIViewController that supports all orientations. It presents an View controller which supports only Portrait orientation and this view has an Text Field. When TextField becomes first responder Keyboard view is poped up. Now, if I change the device orientation, keyboard changes its orientation to Landscape.

How do I keep the keyboard in Portrait orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create an iVar called `UIInterfaceOrientation previousOrientation`.

When you say `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` add:

```
[viewController shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

// Set the previousOrientation to whatever it was
previousOrientation = viewController.interfaceOrientation

// This prevents it from leaving portrait orientation
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Then in `[textField resignFirstResponder]`, when the user closes the keyboard or presses enter;
You can revert to the original orientation.

```
[ViewController shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:previousOrientation];

// Turn the notifications back on so that it will be able to rotate again
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Comment: As I said, I want by ViewController to be in Device Orientation. My Keyboard View should be always in Portrait mode irrespective of device orientation. How do I do this?

Comment: The keyboard's orientation is set by the device's orientation at that moment. You'll have to manually set it like the above or it won't change. Also, why would you have a horizontal keyboard with a landscape UITextField out of curiosity?

Comment: I have an UIViewController and its view has to work is all the orientations. When user taps on one of the option provided in this view and modal view controller is presented and its view has text fields. When this text field becomes first responder keyboard view is presented. Now if user changes the orientation to landscape, the the presented modal view and keyboard should not change its orientation [should be always in Portrait]. When the modal view controller is dismissed, the UIViewController vc should change its orientation or should be in landscape.

Comment: See edits, that should be what you want. It temporarily reorients the viewController so that you can type in portrait, then returns to the original orientation whatever that may be.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need Portrait Orientation u can disable Autorotation with:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one problem in using this. If I disable notifications, now if I change to Landscape it works as expected. But, when the modal view controller is dismissed, my first UIViewController [that presented another UIViewController] should be in current device orientation. since we disabled notifications when device orientation changed, my UIViewController will not be auto-rotated.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but if you just need to disable the rotation while the keyboard is active, disable it by observing `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` an turn it back on by observiing `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, you can do it in the appropriate callback methods of the `UITextViewDelegate`