# iphone keyboard is rotating into landscape while app setting is portrait only

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My app’s device orientation is set to portrait, however when rotating the device into landscape mode, the app is keeping its portait mode but the keyboard is rotating into landscape mode...Something that is unexpected.

Why is that happening and how to prevent it?

Thanks
Jrejory

Comment: can you post a screenshot along with the code of viewcontroller causing this problem?

Comment: I was going to do that however my reputation did not allow that.try 1- http://postimg.org/image/qd23e4tsr/  2- http://postimg.org/image/da9wq0pxd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not getting any answer and making more researches, I came across this Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941930/4400274

Because I just needed the portrait orientation in my app the following worked for me :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

I put that in my main Navigation Controller's viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. But maybe it will help someone else. I had the similar issue. My app should support portrait orientation for iPhone and all orientations for iPad. So, on the iPhone scene didn't rotate, but keyboard did. All my UI was made from code, I also init view controllers (including root) through code. But I didn't remove default Main.storyboard file. When I removed string in Target -> General -> Main Interface, it help me. It was not obvious.