# Temporarily disable rotation for keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I'm working on a iOS keyboard extension - and would like to temporarily disable rotation of the keyboard. The reason is that we use the keyboard view also for settings, since the settings bundle for keyboards extensions were (still are?) broken when we started development.

Basically, we change the size of the keyboard to full screen, and render the settings view there. However, we would prefer to always show settings in portrait orientation - regardless of the orientation of the device.

Is this possible - or will I be forced to implement settings in both landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6942354/2535467

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. 
It still rotates when I turn the notifications off.
Aren't most of the orientation API's deprecated, in favour of size classes, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Preventing a View From Rotating](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html) Q&A in Apple's iOS Developer Library - I will give it a try.