# Disable rotation of custom keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, uideviceorientation, viewwilltransitiontosize

I am creating a custom keyboard and I don't want to support for landscape mode. So, if a user rotates device to landscape mode then the keyboard must still be in portrait mode. I have tried the following methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPotrait];
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

But none of the methods works. The only method fires while rotating the device  is this:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
      withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

Here I'm getting the current view size after rotation. But how do I stop the rotation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941849/disable-orientation-for-keyboard-in-iphone

Comment: @Ariel : I already tried that. Not working.

Comment: I am also making a custom keyboard, and am using Auto layouts to maintain the portrait and landscape mode. I have the same case as yours.

Are you using Auto layouts or disabling the auto layout for now?

Comment: I'm using autolayout but I don't have support for landscape mode. I want that the same keyboard of portrait mode should also open for landscape mode.

Comment: My keyboard uses autolayout too. Are you noticing a 4-5 second delay when keyboard loads on device? I am noticing a 4-5 second delay in my keyboard. And, about your case, friend. I'm afraid I have had bad experiences with portrait only keyboards. The keyboards that support portrait only had bad layout issues when I switched to landscape mode. Seems, a custom keyboard must confirm to the app's layout that requested the keyboard in the first place.

Comment: @Ariel: yes,  I am experiencing  a 4-5 second delay in my keyboard.

Comment: Please run the project in release mode and install it to the device, not simulator. And, tell me if you still get the delay or not? It might cause you hours of trouble like me. If you need instructions, I can help you on that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a custom keyboard for your app itself, then It should be controllable.

Ideally the orientation is inherited from the last heirarchial or the current visible view Controller of the app.

But if you are creating a third party keyboard application then Custom keyboard is kind of app overlayed on other app where as the orientation is still inherited from the app which is in the keywindow currently. I think custom keyboard cannot be limited to a particular orientation so that user feels convienient in using all the apps with that custom keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the same on `viewDidAppear`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPotrait];
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Comment: I have tried but its not working for custom keyboard viewcontroller